# ¿Por qué Google Chrome malinterpreta la regla @media screen orientation en dispositivos móviles?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

La pregunta puede ser un tanto confusa, pues bien, me voy a explicar un poco.
Resulta que estaba creando un formulario, el cual tenía determinados estilos que cambiaban dependiendo de una regla `@media` de **CSS** (**en este caso con la orientación**).

**[Todo esto lo estoy probando con la pantalla en vertical]**

Cuando visualizaba la página en mi iPad se veía todo correctamente, pues bien, cogí mi teléfono (Android) y abrí mi página usando Google Chrome, y sí, también se mostraba correctamente, pero el problema viene ahora, cuando pulso en un `<input>` para escribir en él, el navegador reconoce la pantalla como si estuviese en horizontal, pero lo mejor de todo es que esto solo me ocurre cuando pulso sobre un `<input>` de tipo texto `<input type="text">`, sin embargo cuando pulso sobre un `<input>` de tipo número `<input type="number">` **el navegador sigue reconociendo que la pantalla está en vertical (que es lo correcto)**.

Después de esto me hice un pequeño ejemplo para ver el ancho y el alto de la ventana del navegador en píxeles, para ello puse dos `inputs` dentro de un contenedor, uno de ellos de tipo `text` y el otro de tipo `number`.
Una vez teniendo esto listo me puse a probarlo, **[el tamaño de la ventana al cargar la página era de `1012x1530`]**, cuando pulsaba el `<input type="number">` el tamaño de la ventana se reducía a `1012x1033` **=> sigue siendo vertical**, sin embargo al pulsar el  el tamaño de la ventana pasa a ser de `980x912` **=> ya no puede ser reconocido como vertical, el ancho está siendo superior al alto**, lo cual `CSS` ya no está aplicando el estilo que tengo establecido para una pantalla vista en vertical.

Aquí dejo unos ejemplos gráficos:

> En esta imagen, se muestra la resolución nada más cargar la página:
>   [image]
>
> En esta otra, pulsando sobre el `<input type="number">`:
>   [image]
>
> Y por último pulsando en el `<input type="text">`
>
> [image]

También voy a dejar adjuntado el pequeño guión que hice para realizar este ejemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = window.innerWidth +'x'+window.innerHeight;
            }, 200); 
        });

    </script>

<style>

    #log {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    #container {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 40%;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }

    input {
        width: 80%;
        font-size: 30px;
        background: transparent;
        color: #666;
        margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
        border: 2px solid #888;
    }

    @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {

        #container {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="log"></div>
    <div id="container">

        <label for="text">Text:</label>
            <input id="text" type="text"><br>

        <label for="number">Number:</label>
            <input id="number" type="number">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> NOTA: esto solamente me ocurre (por lo menos hasta lo que he
>   conseguido probar) en **Opera** y en **Google Chrome** (en sistemas operativos
>   Android), sin embargo **en sistemas operativos iOS no ocurre esto**, funciona perfectamente con ambos tipos de `<input>`. He podido apreciar con mi ejemplo de código, que al **probarlo en iOS, las dimensiones de la pantalla no se alteraban**.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda posible :)

Comment: ¿te pasa lo mismo si quitas el `jquery` y el `<script>` de tu index ?

Comment: @AXL sí, me pasa de cualquier modo

Comment: Prueba a añadir el meta <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> en el head.

Comment: @FernandoCabrera tampoco, probé muchas cosas ya antes de publicar la pregunta, pero nada

Comment: @Javi, si no me equivoco tu mismo tienes la respuesta y el porque de tu problema como has comentado en tu [pregunta en el foro de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337711/why-google-chrome-is-a-affecting-to-my-css-media-queries/44337795#44337795)

Comment: @AXL pero sigo sin saber como resolverla, la solucion que me das es usando píxeles y eso sería muy pesado hacerlo, porque si no, no entiendo para qué está esa querie.

Comment: Quizás no me haya expresado bien. Lo que yo te recomiendo es **testear** + y mejor, con muchos dispositivos distintos, con diferentes navegadores en diferentes SO, con todo lo que esté al alcance de tu mano para que asi, puedas ponderar con una visión más amplia la *gravedad* de ese problema. Es verdad que a veces, y a todos nos ha pasado, nos obcecamos por como se ve algo en nuestro móvil, tablet, etc y perdemos un poco de vista esa visión global. Tambien cierto es, que el RWD no es magia y no satisface SIEMPRE a todos. A veces nos toca escoger entre el menor de los males por desgracia

Comment: @AXL gracias por tus comentarios, intentaré investigar más sobre el problema, lo que si que vi en el foro inglés fue una solución que lo arreglaba en unos dispositivos pero lo estropeaba en otros, y claro tampoco me convence, no si es algo malo o algo bueno pero cuando quiero que algo quede de algún modo tiene que ser así, y hasta que no lo consigo no paro, pero este problema en concreto se me está haciendo muy molesto y duradero.

Comment: Suerte, amigo. Ya nos contarás como te sales de esta ;)

Comment: @AXL no se si tu también tenías este problema, pero ya he puesto una respuesta con la solución. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al fin encontré la manera de resolver este problema, aunque en el ejemplo no aparezca la mención del tag `<meta name="viewport"` en las pruebas que hice si estaba y en el atributo `content` de éste, es donde estaba el fallo, dicho esto voy a detallar el fallo y después la solución que he conseguido darle:

El viewport que estaba usando era el siguiente:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
```

El problema estaba en `width=device-width` y en `height=device-height`, esto lo que estaba provocando era que **el tamaño de la pantalla se actualizase en todo momento**, es decir, **cuando el teclado se abría para escribir en el `<input>` el ancho de la pantalla cambiaba al igual que el alto de la pantalla**, entonces  podrían darse dos casos, o bien que la pantalla siguiese en vertical o bien que la pantalla cambiase a horizontal (**obviamente esto dependería del tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo que se estuviera utilizando**), por esa misma razón no ocurre en todos los dispositivos. Una vez conocido el problema me di cuenta que la solución era relativamente sencilla, y esta es simplemente establecer **un alto inicial y un ancho inicial (al cargar el documento)**, por lo tanto, ahora cuando pinchemos en el `<input>` para escribir en el teclado **el tamaño de la pantalla no cambiará**.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=400, height=500, initial-scale=1">
```

De ese modo cuando la pantalla tenga un ancho mayor a 400 píxeles, el navegador extenderá el viewport (en lugar de acercar el zoom) para ajustarlo a la pantalla, (exactamente lo mismo para el alto).

Por lo tanto el **width** y el **height** deberán contener el mínimo valor que tu página necesita para verse correctamente.

Espero que sirva de ayuda

Comment: interesante, gracias por el aporte!

Comment: @AXL de nada! Espero que sirva de ayuda :)